# TSQL Trying to clean up and cast a messy string field to a decimal to perform a SUM function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

I'm tyring to write some SQL to achieve the following.

"Show me daily results detailing the number of Quotes and the sum of their assocaiated fares where the Fare isn't null and QuoteOrBooking equals 'Quote'".

So, given the below table, I'm looking for the result of:

```
Date        Quotes  TotalValue
2013-08-06  3       228.00
2013-08-07  2       80.00
```

As you can see the Fare is a (rather messy) string field so I need to clean it up and cast to a decimal. This is the bit I'm stuck on. The example below shows the extent of the issues (i.e. if I can get it working for this data it'll work for the entire database).

I think I'm messing up my use of REPLACE and I am unsure if the existence of a period (.) is acceptable or not when trying to convert a string to a decimal.

```
+-------------+------------+----------------+
| BookingDate | Fare       | QuoteOrBooking |
+-------------+------------+----------------+
| 2013-08-06  | NULL       | Quote          |
| 2013-08-06  | 21         | Booking        |
| 2013-08-06  | 97         | Quote          |
| 2013-08-06  | £131       | Quote          |
| 2013-08-07  | 21.00      | Quote          |
| 2013-08-07  | 59.        | Quote          |
| 2013-08-07  | NULL       | Quote          |
| 2013-08-07  | 97         | Booking        |
+-------------+------------+----------------+
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Many thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's all `MONEY` to me:

```
SELECT CAST(Fare AS MONEY)
FROM Table1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7595/2/0)

Full query:

```
SELECT  BookingDate
       ,COUNT(*)
       ,SUM(CAST(Fare AS MONEY))
FROM Table1
WHERE QuoteOrBooking = 'Quote' 
     AND Fare IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY BookingDate
ORDER BY BookingDate
```

OR:

```
SELECT  BookingDate
       ,COUNT(Fare)
       ,SUM(CAST(Fare AS MONEY))
FROM Table1
WHERE QuoteOrBooking = 'Quote' 
GROUP BY BookingDate
ORDER BY BookingDate
```

Comment: +1 very nice and easy solution.  I didn't know MONEY would take/strip money identifiers.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the help. Very elegant. 

In the end I did need a REPLACE function as some of the values had white space that I needed to strip out: 

    SUM(CAST(REPLACE(Fare, ' ', '') AS MONEY))